# Access object variables of object?

Tags: java, string, queue

I'm trying to see how i would go about getting the Customer objects name and food, when it is already added to a queue? So say i'd like to print a string using from the name and food elements of the first customer object after its been added to the queue? The queue peek methods are place holders because I'm not sure how to access the object's name and food after it's been added to the queue.

Result would be something like this:

"What do you want to process: pizza or salad?

salad

James’s salad is done!"

Code:

Main class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File customerTxt = new File("customer.txt");
        Queue<Customer> pizza = new LinkedList<Customer>();
        Queue<Customer> salad = new LinkedList<Customer>();
        try {
            Scanner readCus = new Scanner(customerTxt);
            Scanner readFood = new Scanner(System.in);
            while (readCus.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = readCus.nextLine();
                String[] strArray = line.split(",");
                String customerName = strArray[0];
                String customerFood = strArray[1];
                Customer cus = new Customer(customerName, customerFood);
                if (customerFood.equalsIgnoreCase("salad")) {
                    salad.add(cus);
                }
                if (customerFood.equalsIgnoreCase("pizza")) {
                    pizza.add(cus);
                }
            }
            if (pizza.isEmpty() == false && salad.isEmpty() == false) {
                System.out.println("What kind of food would you like to make?");
                String foodChoice = readFood.nextLine();
                if (foodChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("salad")) {
                    System.out.println(salad.peek());
                }
                if (foodChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("pizza")) {
                    System.out.println(salad.peek());
                }
            }
            if (pizza.isEmpty() == true && salad.isEmpty() == false) {
                System.out.println("There are no Pizzas left to process. I will just finish the rest of the Salads");
                while (salad.isEmpty() == false) {
                    System.out.println(salad.peek());
                }
            }
            if (pizza.isEmpty() == false && salad.isEmpty() == true) {
                System.out.println("There are no Salads left to process. I will just finish the rest of the Pizzas");
                while (pizza.isEmpty() == false) {
                    System.out.println(pizza.peek());
                }
            }
        }

        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Customer Class:

```
public class Customer {

    public String name = "";

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String food = "";

    public String getFood() {
        return food;
    }

    public void setFood(String food) {
        this.food = food;
    }

    public Customer(String customerName, String customerFood) {
        this.name = customerName;
        this.food = customerFood;
    }



    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your classes have `get` and `set` methods which are used for accessing the attributes of a class.

So simply:

```
String food = cus.getFood(); //food now contains what is contained in the food variable of your cus object
cus.setName("Bob"); //The name of your customer is now Bob
```

will allow you to get/set food strings and customer names.

Comment: Yes, but how would you access the Queue to look at the first queue element (which is a customer object) and get its food and name variables? sorry i may have not worded the question well

Comment: `Customer c = pizza.remove()` will give you the element at the head of the queue. I recommend you look at the Queue java documentation. Will help a lot.